# Extracting information from the XML using DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/javascript;version=1.7">
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET","file:///Users/me/folder/items.xml", false); 
    req.send(null);
    var dom = req.responseXML;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is the code that is given to me - I am supposed to pull objects from items.xml and inject them into the body of this file.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.responseXML` property is a document object<sup>*[1]</sup>, which represent the document tree of your parsed XML object. The `.appendChild` can be used to append nodes from the XML document to your body:

```
document.body.appendChild(dom);
```

It's also possible to select a specific element of the XML tree, using DOM methods/properties, such as `.getElementsByTagName("tag_name")`, `.childNodes`, etc. 
If you prefer a string, use `.xml` (IE) or `XMLSerializer` to get a string representation of the document:

```
var string = dom.xml ?
    dom.xml
   : new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(dom);
```

<sup>*1</sup> The `.responseXML` will be `null` if the response is invalid.